# Camel Netty4 component tcp client reconnect limit

Tags: apache-camel, netty

I have an application that uses Camel Netty4 component as a consumer endpoint which is configured as a TCP client (clientMode set to true) with the reconnect option enabled. The reconnect feature works well, the TCP client automatically reconnects to the remote server after a connection outage. Unfortunately it seems that this reconnect behavior runs indefinitely until the connection is established. Is there some way to set a limit to this reconnect feature, i.e. put a limit on how many reconnect attempts can be made before throwing a connection error?

Another question but this one is for the Netty4 component implemented as a producer that sends a payload to a remote server. Is there a way to configure the endpoint to enable the reconnect feature which would allow the TCP client to try establish a connection for a number of attempts before throwing a connection error?

Answer (score 1):

In Camel 2.17-SNAPSHOT, there is no way to limit the amount of reconnection attempts. The reconnection is handled by `ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory#scheduleReconnect`. See [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-netty4/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/netty4/ClientModeTCPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java#L207-L220).

Currently it doesn't track the number of attempts, but it would be pretty simple to implement this functionality by adding a counter inside the anonymous `Runnable`.

Could you please open a ticket in the [Camel JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont think limit for retry feature is avaialble at present for consumer, but you can specify the interval in which these retries can happen , the timeunit is in milliseconds.